# PHP: Get all values from an "row" in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to know how get the sum of all values in a specific "row" of an array.

I got this array for example:

```
[0] {array( "date" => "2015-01-01", "value" => 5) }
[1] {array( "date" => "2015-01-02", "value" => -3) }
...
```

Now I would like to get the sum of all "values" in this array - in this case it would be 2.

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: What you have tried so far. Post your attempts

Comment: `array_sum(array_column($array, 'value'));`

Comment: WIth................................. `array_sum` and i'm not joking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) fits that description rather nicely, don't you?

```
$values = array_column($array, 'value');
var_dump($values);
```

And the aptly named [`array_sum`](http://php.net/array_sum) will finish it all off nicely

```
$sum = array_sum($values);
```

In case you're still on PHP5.4 (`array_column` wasn't introduced until 5.5):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($array as $sub)
{
    $sum += $sub['value'];
}
```

will do just fine. It'll probably outperform the `array_column` + `array_sum` approach anyway (because it's not calling functions, but relying on language constructs)

Comment: to whomever down-voted: I don't mind, if you can explain why you down-voted. I'll amend my answer if needed

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific function for this: [array_reduce](http://nl.php.net/array_reduce)

```
<?php
$array = array(array('date'=>'', value=>5),array('date'=>'', value=>-3));

$t = array_reduce($array, function($result, $item){
    $result['value'] = $result['value'] + $item['value']; 
    return $result;
}, array('value'=>0));
```

array reduce gets an array, a function to use on that array, and the third paramter is the initial array you use on the first call of the function.

I used an array here so you can, if you want, also do something with the date (max or min). You could ofcourse just use an int. Then it looks simpeler:

```
$t = array_reduce($array, function($result, $item){
    $result = $result + $item['value']; 
    return $result;
}, 0);
```

Comment: You can simply use `$result += $item['value']; `

Comment: indeed you can, not much difference one way or the other ofcourse

Comment: Best use of `array_reduce` indeed +1

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a combination of [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) like so:

```
$sum = array_sum(
    array_column(
        $originalArray,
        'value'
    )
);
```

If you're on an older version of PHP (< 5.5.0), then you could use the following:

```
$sum = array_sum(
    array_map(
        function($arr) {
            return $arr['value'];
        },
        $originalArray
    )
);
```